# IE8 compatability - css backgrounds and border

Tags: wordpress, css

I have some css used on a wordpress site. It looks as it should in chrome/safari etc but typically not correct in IE8.

The div has a background colour and moz-border-radius used for the border.The border is not important however the background colour only extends part of the way, or in the case of IE8, not at all.

Example: http://mesirow.btg340.co.uk

If you see the newsletter signup form midway down the page, in Chrome etc it has a nice blue background coupled with the border. However in IE its just showing as a white background and ignoring most of the styling.

If you then view: http://mesirow.btg340.co.uk/industries/airlines/

The newsletter signup is on the right hand sidebar. In IE8 the background only stretches half way?

This is no doubt css related. Ive tried various changes such as using fixed height etc but so far no luck :(

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears you are using some html5 markup (`aside`), which IE8 does not automatically understand properly.  You need to do some standard styling to make `aside`, `section`, and other html5 elements `display:block`, etc.

Comment: This is a classic case of not clearing your floats. Add `overflow: hidden` to `.wpmlwidget` and read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/).

Comment: Thanks both, the overflow: hidden seems to have worked for the sidebar area, but the home page one still doesnt show any background?

Comment: @Wayners247 it is not working on the home page for the reasons mentioned by @cale_b. IE8 is taking it as invalid markup and rendering its content outside of it. As the `background-color` is on the `aside` element it is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `<aside>` tag that's why it's an Invalid Markup for IE 8

Comment: If you add a line of JavaScript in the head of your page to create an element called `aside` — i.e. `document.createElement('aside');` — it should start working. See http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Answer (score 0):

Using html5 markup in ie8/7 is causing the problem.

If you use http://modernizr.com/ it comes with an html5 shiv and should allow for html5 tags in ie7/8..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve this question...:)

please check your html code

```
 <aside id="wpmlwidget-2" class="wpmlwidget">....</aside>
```

please replace your aside code with div this will work..aside code not supported in ie-8.

```
 <div id="wpmlwidget-2" class="wpmlwidget">....</div>
```

and for border radius in ie-7 or ie-8 possible via java script check this link http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners